# How to do conditional logic using redux middleware?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand how to use redux middleware and attach it to `applyMiddleware`, I'm struggling on how to cancel actions or dispatch different actions depending on something

I have a shop app. if the user decreases the quantity of an item I want my middleware to interact with it if the quantity is going to go from 1 to 0 and a modal to pop up saying, "are you sure you want to remove from your basket?" and then if they click yes, the action completes. if they click no, the action cancels

```
const modalMiddleware = store => next => action => {
 console.log(action)
  if (action.type === 'DECREMENT_QUANTITY'){
   } else {
    next(action)
   }
}
```

this is what I have so far. how can I cancel the action inside the if block?

updated part:

basically if the quantity of the item is 1 and the person tries to click `-` button that triggers the `DECREMENT_QUANTITY` action, I want to say: "are you sure you want to remove this item from the basket?" (because obviously 1 to 0 === deleting it). and then if they click "yes", i will continue the action, if no, cancel it.

but so far when I do this:

```
const modalMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  if ( action.updatedItem && action.type === 'DECREMENT_QUANTITY' ){
    if (action.updatedItem && action.type === 'DECREMENT_QUANTITY' && action.updatedItem.quantity === 1){
        console.log(store.getState().bag.products[0].quantity, 'quants')
      } else {
      next(action)
    }
  } else {
    next(action)
  }
}
```

it only seems to be doing this when the quantity is at 2. i.e. when it gets to 2 and i click `-` then it remains at 2. but i cant seem to do it at 1 :/

Comment: The action will only continue if you call `next(action)`

Comment: ok makes sense. but what I'm confused as that if I say `if (action.updatedItem && action.type === 'DECREMENT_QUANTITY' && action.updatedItem.quantity === 0)`, then this point it's too late and the item has been deleted :/ and if i say `=== 1` then it seems to stop at quantity: 2 and never get to 1 :/

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Perhaps updating the original question would help clarify your point.

Comment: @djfdev have updated, please see below original post

Comment: @djfdev my bad I figured it out. i already had the logic somewhere else. fixed now!